# Command-C does not copy highlighted text into clipboard from MacVim

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina, copy-paste, macvim

I just installed `macVim`/`mvim` on macOS Catalina and uncertain why the  normal macOS shortcuts are not working. They work on my other macOS Mojave system. There are probably some settings I am missing here.

This is what I have in `~/.vim` directory.

[image]

**Update** Responding to question about the configuration on both systems: I used the *copy from another mac* to initialize the new system (that does not work) from the old system (that does) . That led to the entire home directory being bulk copied: so the configs are the same in both.

**Another update**  Corrected above to say `vim _directory_` (not `vim _file_`)   Also here are contents of couple of those files

```
$cat gvimrc
set guifont=Menlo:h10
```

Under `.vim/plugin` we have:

```
$ll plugin
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  6747 May  6  2017 cua-mode.vim
drwxr-xr-x  3 steve  staff    96 May  6  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 steve  staff   224 Mar 13 12:18 ..
```

The `cua-mode.vim` is here 
 https://gist.github.com/javadba/a639e8e75e63dfe0499679b3f78635e5 . As for all the other files this is working on the first machine and not the new one.

Comment: Did you check whether your config is the same on both systems?

Comment: Also please copy/paste Terminal output as text (and format as code), it's easier to read that way (especially for people with screen readers) and the text then also shows up in search.

Comment: @nohillside  The systems have identical home directories: updated the question.  wrt `Terminal output`  that seems to be orthogonal to whether the text from `Macvim` were copied to the clipboard. Please clarify

Comment: You have a screenshot from Terminal in your question. Please replace this with copied text (of the same content of course)

Comment: Oh I see the confusion: i corrected to say `vim _directory_` from `vim _file_`  : so the screenshot is not useful for anything wrt copy and paste or search.  In any case i added details on some of the files